# How do I contact someone in Canonical's organization?

Tags: canonical, contacts, ubuntu-email-address

I'm seeking a contact for Canonical's public relations person within the organization. Can anyone provide a phone number or email for this person? Or, at least, some jumping off point to find the information myself?

Thanks in advance.
Jake

PS: For admins or anyone with access to my email address, please feel free to contact me via email with the information.

Comment: why not try their [official contact form](http://www.canonical.com/services/contact-us) ?

Answer (score 2):

here you go ! this is the official address ! 
[image: Canonical Contact Address]

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware the address was there. @astrob0t: Thanks I'll give that a shot too.